# OpenGL object distortion in perspective view

Tags: c++, opengl, perspective, distortion, glu

Do you guys have any idea what is the cause of this problem? It looks fine in orthographic view.

Orthographic View:

[image]

Perspective View:

[image]

Code that might be related:

```
//Global variable
float tx = 0, tz = 0, tSpeed = 1.0;         
bool isOrtho = true;                
float ONear = -20.0, OFar = 20.0;   
float PNear = 1.0, PFar = 41.0;     
float ptx = 0, pty = 0, ptSpeed = 0.1;  
float pry = 0, prSpeed = 1.0;           

void projection() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    //refer to projection matrix
    glLoadIdentity();               //reset projection matrix

    glTranslatef(ptx, pty, 0.0);    //translation for projection
    glRotatef(pry, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  //rotate for projection
    if (isOrtho) {
        //Ortho View
        glOrtho(-20.0, 20.0, -20.0, 20.0, ONear, OFar); //Ortho view
    }
    else {
        //Perspective view
        gluPerspective(45, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        glFrustum(-20.0, 20.0, -20.0, 20.0, PNear, PFar);
    }
}

void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    projection();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    lighting();
    drawRobot();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the shader source?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use shader in my code.

Comment: Ya, I know I shall probably integrate shader into the program but I do not have too much time left for that because this is actually an assignment that I have to submit by tomorrow and I suspect that the problem shall be somewhere inside the void projection().

Comment: Aright, I have very little experience without shaders, but it looks like the view angle is too large. I would try decreasing it and looking at it from different angles. Sorry I couldn't help any more. =(

Answer (score 0):

The glu docs for [`gluPerspective`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) state:

> zNear
> Specifies the distance from the viewer to the near clipping plane **(always positive)**.

(emphasis mine).

Your code `gluPerspective(45, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);` passes -1.0 for zNear, which is not in the allowed range of values.